# What is the correct structure to use in this comparison?

Tags: grammar, sentence, errors

In this sentence:

> … Richard wrote his book very enthusiastically and elaborately, and thus it was more popular.

What should replace the ellipsis?

1. Unlike those of his colleagues
2. Unlike books of his colleagues
3. Not like his colleagues
4. Comparing his colleagues
5. Unlike his colleagues

I know option 5 is the correct answer. Why are options 3 and 4 incorrect? What is the correct structure to use for *Not like* and *Comparing*?

Comment: You need to edit your question as there is neither C nor D. You don't need to put so many question marks, either. Unless you edit your question in accordance with the guidelines of our Help Center, your question will be closed and ultimately deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The reason 3 is wrong is not because of grammar, it's just not the way this concept is generally phrased.

4 is wrong because *comparing* is an active verb, so it would be taken to mean that Richard is comparing his colleagues. If you want to use this word to express a distinction, you say *compared **to** his colleagues* or *in comparison **with** his colleagues*. You need to use a preposition to express that you're relating things with each other.